# Checkbox on PDF template in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf-generation, peoplesoft, bi-publisher, pdfviewer

We have pdf templates that get data from a data source and write out a file with data in respective fields. It uses PeopleSoft delivered functionality to perform this action. What is interesting is, we open the PDF file in Chrome, Safari, IE and other browsers, a check appears (shown below) in the checkboxes. But when we open the same file, from the same run in a Firefox browser window, they appear as 4s (image below) instead of a check in the checkbox. 
Does anyone have an idea if this is a known issue? Any help is appreciated.

[image: This is how the checkbox looks in Chrome and other browsers]

[image: This is how the checkbox looks in Firefox]

Comment: I just noticed that this happens only when the PDF files is opened in the online PDF viewer on Firefox. If I download the file from the viewer and open it using Adobe, the checkboxes have checks in them.

Comment: As it indicates itself, PDF.js (the FF embedded PDF viewer) doesn't support AcroForm. You may want to provide a real Web form so that user can fill your PDF whatever is their browser or local PDF viewer.